# Pagination doesn't work after perform search

Tags: pagination, laravel-5.1

I have a form in Laravel. I used `pagination` in this form and search option too. Pagination works fine when I didn't search anything. If I search something which has records more than 10 (my pagination record limit is 10), it shows result perfectly in first page but in second page or third page it shows the records of whole database. It's ignore the search criteria.

**Controller Code:**

```
public function index()
{
    if (Input::has('invoiceNumber')) {
        $invoiceNumber = Input::get('invoiceNumber');
        $invoices = Invoice::where('invoiceNumber','like', '%'.$invoiceNumber.'%')->orderBy('date','desc')->paginate(10);
    } elseif (Input::has('client')) {
        $client = Input::get('client');
        $invoices = Invoice::where('client','like', '%'.$client.'%')->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    } elseif (Input::has('startDate') && Input::has('endDate')) {
        $startDate = Input::get('startDate');
        $endDate = Input::get('endDate');
        $invoices = Invoice::whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    } elseif (Input::has('startDate')) {
        $startDate = Input::get('startDate');
        $invoices = Invoice::where('date', $startDate)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    } elseif (Input::has('endDate')) {
        $endDate = Input::get('endDate');
        $invoices = Invoice::where('date', $endDate)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    } else {
        $invoices = DB::table('invoices')
            ->join('vehicles', 'invoices.vehicle', '=', 'vehicles.registration')
            ->select(
                'invoices.*',
                'vehicles.brand',
                'vehicles.model',
                'vehicles.seat',
                'vehicles.remarks'
            )
            ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
    }
    return view('invoice.index',compact('invoices'));
}
```

After performing search my URL look like this:

```
http://my-site.com/invoice?invoiceNumber=&client=&startDate=2016-01-01&endDate=2016-02-08
```

After this search when I click on page 2, the URL become this:

```
http://my-site.com/invoice?page=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view file, the render has to be like given below:

```
{!! $invoices->appends(Input::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this bellow code (change as per your requirement)

```
return view('invoice.index')->withInvoices($invoices->appends(Input::except('page'));
```

Hope it's working for you...

Comment: Thank you. This one also works fine. But @Jilson Thomas answered first, so I should accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this on the result page.Pagination will be automatically visible at the bottom of the page

```
{!! $invoices->render() !!}
```

Comment: I had this before. But I needed pagination with the search results. Anyway, I have got the answer.