# Opencart (3.0.1): Pagination doesn't work after search

Tags: php, search, pagination, opencart

I have an web store based on the OpenCart 3.0.1.

The representation on the screen is so called "endless scroll" when new items are loaded while you are scrolling (auto page loading). 9 elements are loaded at once (page). The procedure of search shows maximum 9 items relevant and then, when you are scrolling down, starts loading and showing everything else available in db.

It feels to be the same issue as in here: [Pagination doesn't work after perform search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262401/pagination-doesnt-work-after-perform-search)

What is the possible way to fix it?

My code of search procedure is (module\catalog\product.php):

```
    public function mainSearch($term)
{
    $products = $this->searchByProductName($term);
    $manufactures = $this->searchByManufacturer($term);
    $items = [];
    $this->load->model('tool/image');
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $id = $product['product_id'];
        $items[$id]['id'] = $id;
        $items[$id]['text'] = $product['name'];
        $items[$id]['type'] = 'product';
        $items[$id]['manufacturer'] = $product['manufacturer'];
        if ($product['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
        } else {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
        }
        $items[$id]['image'] = $image;
        $items[$id]['link'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $id);
    }
    foreach ($manufactures as $manufacture) {
        $id = $manufacture['manufacturer_id'];
        $items[$id]['id'] = $id;
        $items[$id]['text'] = $manufacture['name'];
        $items[$id]['type'] = 'manufacturer';
        if ($manufacture['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($manufacture['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
        } else {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
        }
        $items[$id]['image'] = $image;
        $items[$id]['link'] = $this->url->link('product/category/index', 'path=' . MAIN_CATEGORY . '&filters[manufacturer]=' . $id);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

My code of pagination seem to be (controller\product\category.php)

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->language('product/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
        $filter = $this->request->get['filter'];
    } else {
        $filter = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
    } else {
        $sort = 'p.sort_order';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $order = $this->request->get['order'];
    } else {
        $order = 'ASC';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $page = $this->request->get['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
        $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
    } else {
        $limit = $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
    );

    if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $path = '';

        $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

        $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

        foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
            if (!$path) {
                $path = (int)$path_id;
            } else {
                $path .= '_' . (int)$path_id;
            }

            $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

            if ($category_info) {
                $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text' => $category_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path . $url)
                );
            }
        }
    } else {
        $category_id = 0;
    }

    $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

    if ($category_info) {
        $this->document->setTitle($category_info['meta_title']);
        $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
        $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);

        $data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];

        $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));

        // Set the last category breadcrumb
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $category_info['name'],
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'])
        );

        if ($category_info['image']) {
            $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_height'));
        } else {
            $data['thumb'] = '';
        }

        $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $result['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
            );
        }
        $data['products'] = array();

        if (isset($this->request->get['filters'])) {
            $filters = $this->request->get['filters'];
        } else {
            $filters = [];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $search = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $search = [];
        }

        $filter_data = array(
            'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
            'filter_filter'      => $filter,
            'sort'               => $sort,
            'order'              => $order,
            'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,
            'limit'              => $limit,
            'filters' => $filters,
            'search' => $search,
        );

        $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
            } else {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$result['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                $rate_special = round(100 - ((float)$result['special'] / $result['price'] * 100));
            } else {
                $special = false;
                $rate_special = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $tax = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }

            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'rate_special' => $rate_special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'year' => $result['year'],
                'label' => $result['label'],
                'country' => $result['country'],
                'production_year' => $result['production_year'],
                'states' => $this->model_catalog_product->getHtmlStates($result['vinyl_state'], $result['cover_state']),
                'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
            );
        }

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['sorts'] = array();

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
            'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
            'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
            'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
            'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
            'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
                'value' => 'rating-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
                'value' => 'rating-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
            );
        }

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
            'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
            'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        $data['limits'] = array();

        $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));

        sort($limits);

        foreach($limits as $value) {
            $data['limits'][] = array(
                'text'  => $value,
                'value' => $value,
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=' . $value)
            );
        }

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination->total = $product_total;
        $pagination->page = $page;
        $pagination->limit = $limit;
        $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');

        $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

        $paginationOld = new Pagination();
        $paginationOld->total = $product_total;
        $paginationOld->page = $page;
        $paginationOld->limit = $limit;
        $paginationOld->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');
        $data['link'] = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path']);

        $data['paginationOld'] = $paginationOld->render();

        $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

        // http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
        if ($page == 1) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id']), 'canonical');
        } else {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. $page), 'canonical');
        }

        if ($page > 1) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . (($page - 2) ? '&page='. ($page - 1) : '')), 'prev');
        }

        if ($limit && ceil($product_total / $limit) > $page) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. ($page + 1)), 'next');
        }

        $data['vinyl_states'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getVinylStates();
        $data['cover_states'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getCoverStates();
        $data['vinyl_types'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getVinylTypes();
        $data['price_min'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getMinPrice();
        $data['price_max'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getMaxPrice();
        $data['year_min'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getMinYear();
        $data['year_max'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getMaxYear();

        $data['sort'] = $sort;
        $data['order'] = $order;
        $data['limit'] = $limit;

        $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            $json = json_encode(['content' => $this->load->view('extension/module/oclayerednavigation/occategory', $data)]);
            $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($json);
            die();
        }

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
    } else {
        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_error'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', $url)
        );

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

        $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        $this->response->addHeader($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('error/not_found', $data));
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion!..